# splice method not showing correct results

Tags: javascript

Hi i am a newbie to Javascript.
i am reading a book where i am learning `splice()` method.
Here is my code

```
 var fruits = ["oranges", "apples", "pears", "grapes"];
        var somefruits = fruits.splice(2, 1, "watermelons");

        for (var i = 0; i < somefruits.length; i++) {
            document.write(somefruits[i] + '<br>');
        };
```

Somehow the result is only showing **pears**.
Can someonetell me why the whole array with watermelons is not replaced.
Thanks,.

Comment: If you want the "whole" array, maybe loop over `fruits` (in which you replaced "pears" by "watermelons") not over `somefruits` (which contains the removed items)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splice will replace the original array and return the values that been replaced.
So in your case:

```
somefruits = fruits.splice(2, 1, "watermelons")
```

somefruits will be the value been replaced which is ["pear"]
and the original fruits value been updated to : ["oranges", "apples", "watermelon", "grapes"]

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini hi, to add a value to original array, you just make the second argument to 0, hence it will not replace anything.